# Memory leak in UIDeviceWhiteColor

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, profiler, xcode14

Any idea how to trace a memory leak in `UIDeviceWhiteColor` as per the profiler?  Ideally it would be great to point to the code.  I have a break on every instance of anything with white in it and no luck.

[image]

Comment: It's coming from a view controller being loaded from a nib/storyboard. Are you sure it's a leak? If the view controller is still in memory then the color isn't leaking.

Comment: Turns out in one of my storyboards, I had User Defined Runtime Attribute called `borderColor` that was not defined in the corresponding @IBDesignable class. Deleting the storyboard attribute, cleared this memory leak.

Comment: by adding `malloc_error_break` breakpoint Xcode was able to point me to this answer with the following: `Failed to set (borderColor) user defined inspected property on (PaddedLabel): [<PaddedLabel 0x107729d10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderColor.`